# SEO and domains

Tags: seo, domains

Is it important for SEO, with which company a domain name is registered?
And more particular - is it okay to have my domain registered here:
[MinmaxGroup](http://minmaxgroup.com/)? Or would be I better off transferring it to [GoDaddy](http://godaddy.com), for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registrar for a domain does not have any impact on SEO. It has nothing to do with the website, its content, or its relevancy for any given search term

Comment: Thank you!
But are you familiar with MinMaxGroup?
How reliable are they?
So far I've been trying to get in touch with them for about two and a half hours, and all in vain.

Comment: That's a pretty good sign that you shouldn't be using them as a registrar.

Comment: That's what I thought.
My client's domain is registered with them.
Would you recommend any decent registrar to transfer the domain to?
Of course, that is if I ever manage to get in touch with MinMax Group.

Comment: If you can look past Godaddy's constant upselling they are inexpensive and reliable.

Comment: One last question - does it matter SEO-wise whether I have hosting and domain registered with the same company or should I keep them separately?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Go with what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter SEO-wise where you purchase or register a domain.

If you also use the same company for hosting it will have an impact on where the domain is hosted and what IP your domain gets, which of course also might have a performance impact as well. Say you host your site in Togo, you might experience slow speeds.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!
For that matter...
Where would you prefer to host a domain out of these four hosting companies? -
http://www.bluehost.com/
http://www.hostgator.com/
http://www.jaguarpc.com/
http://www.stablehost.com/

The company that owns the website is located in NYC and server locals.

Comment: I really can't comment on them, since I haven't yet used any of them. I can wholeheartedly recommend MediaTemple though.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I didn't see your answer and chose inMotionHosting for my client this time.
But I'll keep MediaTemple in mind for the future.